# How can I retrieve information from Json data in a format where almost everything is stored as an array?

Tags: php, json, scrapy

I'm currently using a spider to crawl through reddit and provide me with links and titles in json format. However, when the json file is created the data is stored as individual arrays as shown here:

```
[{"url": ["http://i.imgur.com/1Pw3ehZ.jpg"], "title": ["Sunset in Trinidad, CA", "bungholesex"]},
{"url": ["http://i.imgur.com/neQiFcf.jpg"], "title": ["Humboldt Bay, Eureka California", "bungholesex"]},
{"url": ["http://imgur.com/dxKHGLV"], "title": ["Crater Lake, Oregon in April", "CausticRain11"]},
{"url": ["http://imgur.com/RPv475F"], "title": ["South Dakota is seriously beautiful.", "ratt1601"]},
{"url": ["http://imgur.com/oH1u7nk"], "title": ["The view outside my back door. Virginia is alright, I guess...", "toowhitetofail"]},
```

Whenever I go to retrieve and echo the data converted with json_decoder I receive a notice saying "array to string conversion" but there is no data shown.

Comment: You want transform this json to some other? Than what result format you want?

Comment: Not another format per se but more so editing this data so that names have values in them instead of arrays, if that makes sense.

Comment: `{"url": "http://i.imgur.com/1Pw3ehZ.jpg", "title": "Sunset in Trinidad, CA, bungholesex"}` You want something like this? All items in array are concatenated into one string.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm trying to get. My ultimate goal is to be able to parse through the data by Name and get use the values for various things like entering them into a mysql database. I don't know how to extract the data efficiently in the format I have it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$data = '[{"url": ["http://i.imgur.com/1Pw3ehZ.jpg"], "title": ["Sunset in Trinidad, CA", "bungholesex"]},
{"url": ["http://i.imgur.com/neQiFcf.jpg"], "title": ["Humboldt Bay, Eureka California", "bungholesex"]},
{"url": ["http://imgur.com/dxKHGLV"], "title": ["Crater Lake, Oregon in April", "CausticRain11"]},
{"url": ["http://imgur.com/RPv475F"], "title": ["South Dakota is seriously beautiful.", "ratt1601"]},
{"url": ["http://imgur.com/oH1u7nk"], "title": ["The view outside my back door. Virginia is alright, I guess...", "toowhitetofail"]}]';

$array = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($array as &$item) {
    $item['url'] = $item['url'][0];
    $item['title'] = implode(', ', $item['title']);
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

I am using first array item of `url` because it is always single in your example. And it makes no sense to concatenate urls - resut will not be valid url. But if you want, urls can be concatenated same way as `title`.

Result will look like this:

```
[
  {
    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/1Pw3ehZ.jpg",
    "title": "Sunset in Trinidad, CA, bungholesex"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://i.imgur.com/neQiFcf.jpg",
    "title": "Humboldt Bay, Eureka California, bungholesex"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://imgur.com/dxKHGLV",
    "title": "Crater Lake, Oregon in April, CausticRain11"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://imgur.com/RPv475F",
    "title": "South Dakota is seriously beautiful., ratt1601"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://imgur.com/oH1u7nk",
    "title": "The view outside my back door. Virginia is alright, I guess..., toowhitetofail"
  }
]
```

You can check it [here](https://eval.in/569279).

Answer (score -1):

Your Json above not valid. u should remove , and add ] at the end of your json.
U can check it using json validaor here.

http://jsonlint.com/

```
[{
    "url": ["http://i.imgur.com/1Pw3ehZ.jpg"],
    "title": ["Sunset in Trinidad, CA", "bungholesex"]
}, {
    "url": ["http://i.imgur.com/neQiFcf.jpg"],
    "title": ["Humboldt Bay, Eureka California", "bungholesex"]
}, {
    "url": ["http://imgur.com/dxKHGLV"],
    "title": ["Crater Lake, Oregon in April", "CausticRain11"]
}, {
    "url": ["http://imgur.com/RPv475F"],
    "title": ["South Dakota is seriously beautiful.", "ratt1601"]
}, {
    "url": ["http://imgur.com/oH1u7nk"],
    "title": ["The view outside my back door. Virginia is alright, I guess...", "toowhitetofail"]
}]
```

Comment: This is only a portion of the code. The full json has thousands of rows.